# why is index getting incremented like this? javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

First console log: 0, as expected.
Second console log: 1.
Why index got incremented before the end of loop?

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.offlineTimeSlots.length; i++) {

          console.log(i);

          this.http.post('http://localhost:63203/api', JSON.stringify(this.offlineTimeSlots[i]), { headers: headers })
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => { 

              console.log(i);

              resolve(data);
            }, (err) => {
              reject(err);
            });
        }
```

Comment: because asynchronous code is asynchronous

Comment: these are asynchronous call... so your outer console.log is independent of inner one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.http.post` is the asynchronous function so it will executed separately

For loop will continue its execution and it's not depends on the `this.http.post`.

Concept is called event-loop : [Please read this](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/)

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

When you make an operation inside the for loop like that basically you are generating `this.offlineTimeSlots.length` of http requests (async). Depending on the length of the loop, usually the for loop will complete its loop almost everytime before the http request.

Take a look at this example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    console.log(i);
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(i);
    },2000);
}
```

This will print the numbers from 0 to 10 (10 excluded) and then print 10, ten times. The reason is you are creating 10 (length of the loop) async requests while looping. And since the for loop will finish the traversal quicker than 2 seconds, `i` will be 9 + 1 (post incrementation) by the time `setTimeout`s start.

Source fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/echonax/c9p4e19o/